# How can I write a function to recreate the original text obscured here by css magic?

Tags: python, css, parsing, cryptography, beautifulsoup

I have reached this point out of sheer curiosity. I was trying to dynamically grab some price information from starcitygames/com, and I noticed something very funny. Each price field exists as a series of css div's with garbled class names. eg:

```
<div style='width:55px'><div class="JfaljW">$</div>
<div class="JfaljW SFzEaj sOihDy2">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="XLgCpt2 JfaljW SFzEaj">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="jgsxCy2 JfaljW SFzEaj">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="JfaljW sOihDy2 SFzEaj">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="uwsFle2 SFzEaj JfaljW">&nbsp;</div>
```

would become $16.19 when styled by the following css:

```
<style>.SFzEaj{background-image:url(//sales.starcitygames.com/price_icons.php?id=WI6BlcU6j0IUDd5A07dtIqnclqZEb0kpRAfexYD1SR0);}.JfaljW{width:7px;float:left;height:14px;}.VmnouV{background-position:-28px -2px;}.VmnouV2{background-position:-28px 21px;}.xXiDvn{background-position:-7px -2px;}.xXiDvn2{background-position:-7px 21px;}.mUuibp{background-position:-66px -2px;}.mUuibp2{background-position:-66px 21px;}.SprvYA{background-position:-14px -2px;}.SprvYA2{background-position:-14px 21px;}.XLgCpt{background-position:-42px -2px;}.XLgCpt2{background-position:-42px 21px;}.wfaYmj{background-position:-21px -2px;}.wfaYmj2{background-position:-21px 21px;}.jgsxCy{background-position:-64px -2px;width:3px;}.jgsxCy2{background-position:-64px 21px;width:3px;}.uwsFle{background-position:-56px -2px;}.uwsFle2{background-position:-56px 21px;}.sOihDy{background-position:0px -2px;}.sOihDy2{background-position:0px 21px;}.oliEcx{background-position:-49px -2px;}.oliEcx2{background-position:-49px 21px;}.pQPxxT{background-position:-35px -2px;}.pQPxxT2{background-position:-35px 21px;}</style>
```

Each time that the page loads, the background-image is a different one, defined by the id parameter. A particular image consists of a (semi?) random permutation of the numbers from one to nine.

I would like to write a function that takes the id parameter, and the class names, and recreates the original signal. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: If the id is used to generate the sprite on the fly, then the answer is *yes* if you can reverse engineer the algorithm which you probably can't.

Comment: I'd rather not reverse engineer the algorithm as the id's seem quite long. Is there a way to get from the image back to numbers easily?

Comment: perhaps simply saving a typical version of each digit for comparison would work?

Comment: I haven't looked at the image, but I would think that every image is pretty random.

Comment: If you've seen that the id did repeat at least once, then this might be a viable option, but probably too much work.

Comment: How quickly can one identify the location of each digit in the image? (given a fixed image) .. is this a quick problem to solve?

Comment: Sure, by using character recognition on that sprite.